# Import from `.` `data.table` so that lintr recognizes it

Tags: r, data.table, lintr

When running [lintr](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr) on an R function that uses `data.table` I get the following warning:

```
warning: no visible global function definition for '.', Did you mean '-'?
```

I thought an easy fix would be adding `importFrom data.table .`. I also tried quoting the dot with a backtick but it really doesn't seem to be exported. What is the recommened way to get of this error?

I could add the line

```
`.` <- function(){}
```

somewhere but I didn't get that to work and it's hacky.

Comment: `.` is not a function. data.table [replaces it with `list`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R#L181) before the expression is evaluated. You can define `. <- list` if you simply want to alias list (but that's slightly less efficient).

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I see that data.table developers went out of their way to not alias it so I'm reluctant to do that myself now.

Comment: Well, why do you want to import `.`? If you want to use data.table, I would import the whole package.

Comment: Now that I see that `.` is not even a function I don't want to import `.` it any more. My goal is just to get rid of the lintr warning.

Comment: As an even more fun exercise, we also use the `..` syntax to refer to variables like this `dt[, ..var * 2]` or something. For this lintr gives: `warning: no visible binding for global variable ‘..var’, Did you mean 'var'?`. Yes but no.

Comment: I define `. <- NULL` in my package when I use it. This way `.` is define and R CMD check is happy.

Comment: That works for `R CMD check` but not for `lintr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try quoting the dot with double quotes?
`importFrom data.table "."`

I know this is how I've done imports for the `magrittr` pipe operator

If that doesn't work you can always add the `.` to a `globals.R` file that defines your global variables using `utils::globalVariables()`

```r
if(getRversion() >= "2.15.1")  utils::globalVariables(c("."))
```

Comment: There is no `.` function in package data.table. Thus, you cannot import this function from it.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you can always add the `.` as a global variable to prevent this `devtools::check()` warning

Comment: This seems to work to shut up `lintr`, thanks. I'll do some further testing, hopefully nothing breaks in subtle ways.

Comment: Ah, I see this was a `lintr` problem, not a `devtools` problem. I just remember dealing with this from the devtools side -- glad this worked for `lintr` as well