# How can I use data.table in a package without importing all functions?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, code-translation, dtplyr

I'm building an R package in which I would like to use `dtplyr` to perform various bits of data manipulation. My issue is that `dtplyr` seems to only work if I import the whole of `data.table` (i.e. using the roxygen `#' @import data.table`). Without this I get errors like:

```
Error in .(x = sum(x), y = sum(y),  : 
  could not find function "."
```

If I can solve this problem by only importing certain functions from `data.table` that would be great, but there seems to be no function `.()` in the package. My knowledge of `data.table` is limited, but I can only assume it uses `.()` to edit parsed code (similar to the base R `bquote()`), but that `dtplyr` for some reason needs `data.table` to be loaded for this to work.

I've tried various things such as `withr::with_package("data.table", code)` and `requireNamespace("data.table")`, but so far importing the whole package is the only thing that seems to work. This is not a viable solution because it completely ruins the well-maintained namespace in the package I'm working on by importing so many functions from `data.table`.

NB, this package houses a project which will be worked on by many other analysts well into the future. While simply writing `data.table` code may be preferable in terms of performance and general good-practice, using `dtplyr` to translate `dplyr` code gives a boost in readability and ease-of-use that is far more important in this context.

Comment: Can you try `importFrom data.table ` in the NAMESPACE

Comment: This results in an error when running `devtools::load_all()`: `Error in asChar(ivars) : 
  empty name in directive 'importFrom' in 'NAMESPACE' file` :(

Comment: I think the `importFrom` at two places i.e. NAMESPACE and in the function should have worked `importFrom data.table .`

Comment: Using `#' @importFrom data.table .` then running `document()` and `load_all()` doesn't seem to fix it for me. I get the same error as well as `Warning message:
object ‘.’ is not exported by 'namespace:data.table' ` when running `load_all()`. As I said, I think this is because `data.table` doesn't actually export `.()` as a function

Comment: Can you check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906277/import-from-data-table-so-that-lintr-recognizes-it)

Comment: You might need to import `[` as well as `.`, perhaps `patterns` (not sure what `dtplyr` uses). If the well-maintained namespace is so critical (I'd think your users would not know or care), you could always *exclude* functions you don't want cluttering it. For that, use something like `#' @rawNamespace import(data.table, except=c(transpose))`.

Comment: This does seem like an XY problem. Can you be more specific about the namespace issues you are concerned about when you do the simple `import data.table`?

Comment: Thanks all for your help. After reading some more [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html) I tried using `.datatable.aware = TRUE` inside the package and this seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your question & answer. It would be better to post it as a proper answer, and accept it (no pbl to answer your own question). Then it will be easier to understand the question's solved status

Comment: Thanks, you're very correct! Solution now posted as answer, and question also renamed to reflect the nature of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (documented) solution I found is to set `.datatable.aware <- TRUE` somewhere in the package source code. According to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html), if you're using `data.table` in a package without importing the whole thing, you should do this so that `[.data.table()` does not revert to calling `[.data.frame()`. From the docs:

> ...please define .datatable.aware = TRUE anywhere in your R source code (no need to export). This tells data.table that you as a package developer have designed your code to intentionally rely on data.table functionality even though it may not be obvious from inspecting your NAMESPACE file.