# R | data.table could not find function '.' when a function was created with devtools

Tags: r, data.table, devtools

I use RStudio Workbench.
When I create a simple function like that:

```
sample <- function() {
    df <- data.frame('a' = c(1:10), 'b' = c(1:10))
    dt <- data.table::as.data.table(df)

    return (dt[, .(b)])
}
```

all is fine. When I call this with sample(), there is no error.
The package "data.table" is available in the system library. I didn't load it with library().

When I use "devtools" to create a package. Then I get the error: *Error in .(b) : could not find function "."*

Here is the flow to reproduce the error:

Create the package directory with:

```
devtools::create('home/development/sample', rstudio = FALSE)
```

Save the file "sample.R" in the R directory.

```
#' Example
#'
#' Where is the problem?
#'
#' @return Column 'b' from a data table.
#'
#' @examples
#' \code{sample()}
#'
#' @export
sample <- function() {
    df <- data.frame('a' = c(1:10), 'b' = c(1:10))
    dt <- data.table::as.data.table(df)

    return (dt[, .(b)])
}
```

Document the package and load it.

```
devtools::document('home/development/sample')
devtools::load_all('home/development/sample', export_all = FALSE, reset = TRUE)
sample::sample()
# Console: Error in .(b) : could not find function "."
```

Where could be the problem? Is anything to do with devtools? E.g. with the DESCRIPTION file?
I use data.table with data.table::name() and he used in the global environment the .() syntax. But not with the package? Where I have to load it? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55906277/import-from-data-table-so-that-lintr-recognizes-it

Comment: The code is using `[.data.table` but because `library(data.table)` was not used it cannot find it.

Comment: You could add in roxygen comments :`#' @import data.table`

Comment: See also: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-importing.html

Comment: @G.Grothendieck
When I call "(.packages())", data.table is not loaded. But my first code (not in package) runs. Simple in the global environment. Without loading data.table. Why is this possible?
And when I load it with library(data.table), the code in the package still doesn't run.

Comment: @Waldi
I try it again and now, it runs. Thanks for the answer. I forgot to renew the NAMESPACE in package.

Comment: It seems I was wrong about `[.data.table` .  Simply using `data.table::as.data.table` without using `library` will still load additional methods.

Comment: That is possible. I'm new in R, so every comment or hint helps me :-)

Comment: This error may just be due to package checking so if we define a dummy dot function that may get around it.  Alternately use `list` instead of dot.